# How do I open multiple links in new tabs in Google Chrome?

Tags: macos, keyboard, google-chrome

I am using Google Chrome as my default browser on Lion.

What I want to achieve is, when I select handful of links from one web-page, I should have shortcut to open all those links in new tabs.

How can I achieve this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try one of the extensions [Snaplinks](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/idmmhhijggcmbeejedibpdcahpkneegg) or [Linky](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bknechokhjgchpodgplolmkgicojmgnd)

Comment: I used following Chrome extension: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/linkclump/lfpjkncokllnfokkgpkobnkbkmelfefj?hl=en